# Something like dynamic array

Tags: arrays, instance, monogame

Guy please I want to do something like dynamic array but I don't want to use List.

```
public Texture2D[] spritHouses; 
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    LoadTextures(spritHouses, @"Sprits/Guns/", "Big", "Medium", "Small");
    //The array spritHouses is still null...
}
public void LoadTextures(Texture2D[] texture, string trace, params string[] names)
{
    texture = new Texture2D[names.Count()];
    for (int i = 0; i <= names.Count()-1; i++)
        texture[i] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(trace + names[i]);
}
```

Why the creating of new instance doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's not really clear why you don't want to use List.

Although, based on your code I assume what you really mean is that you want to create an array of textures from a hard coded array of strings (texture names).

But before I show you another way, let me explain why `spriteHouses` is still null.

When you pass the `spritHouses` as parameter to the `LoadTextures` method, what you're actually doing is passing a *copy* of the "value" (i.e. null) to the method. This means that the `texture` variable will be null at the start of the method, but then you're assigning it a new value of `new Texture2D[names.Count()];`.

At this point the `texture` variable has what you want, but when the method returns, this local copy of the array is thrown away and `spriteHouses` is still null. Does that make sense?

Anyway, the simple fix is to return the new array instead of passing it in as a parameter.

```
public Texture2D[] spritHouses; 

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spritHouses = LoadTextures(@"Sprits/Guns/", "Big", "Medium", "Small");
}

public Texture2D[] LoadTextures(string trace, params string[] names)
{
    var textures = new Texture2D[names.Count()];

    for (int i = 0; i <= names.Count()-1; i++)
        textures[i] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(trace + names[i]);

    return textures;
}
```

Comment: Guy,
Thank you for explain this issue.I forget to do it like this and i hadn't known how to do this so i write to help here. I done it yesterday like you writen. But really thank you for help.